# Should we include Graphic Team into Scrumban Process?

Tags: scrum, software-development, kanban, scrumban

Our team familiar with traditional SDLC process like waterfall.
So, We wanna step to scrumban. (we think it suitable for us.)
But we have something to concern and not sure what is best practice for us.
Here is our resource.

1. Graphic Team (5 People)
2. Business Analyst Team (3 People)
3. Develop Team (2 Team, 4 People/Team)
4. Test Team (2 People)

Should I include Graphic Team and Business Analyst to Scrumban? what's the best way?
Thank you in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Similar to, but not a duplicate of : http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/3017/1185

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Steps for moving from waterfall to agile

Looks like you have made the two most important decisions for transforming your software development process:

1. Moving from waterfall to agile.
2. Following the Scrum (or a modified Scrum) process.

Congratulations! You are on the right track. It is possible to work out the other steps from here.

I would say, in order of priority, you should consider the following steps, if you are not doing so already:

1. Send some of your key people for Scrum training.
2. Team size: Looks like you have 18 people. This is too large a team for good communication and collaboration. Try to split this into two teams. [While splitting the teams, make them into feature teams, not component teams.](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/the-benefits-of-feature-teams)
3. Ideally, designate a Scrum Master and a Product Owner for each team. However, you may be able to work with a common Scrum Master for both teams as well as a common Product Owner.
4. Avoid having sub-teams. [Individual Development Team members may have specialized skills and areas of focus, but accountability belongs to the Development Team as a
   whole.](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf) This may be a slow process. But work towards this.

Now to answer your specific question:

> Should I include Graphic Team and Business Analyst to Scrumban? what's
>   the best way?

Yes, you should include Graphic specialists and Business Analysts to the Scrum team.  [Development Teams are cross-functional, with all of the skills as a team necessary to create a product Increment.](https://www.scrum.org/Portals/0/Documents/Scrum%20Guides/2013/Scrum-Guide.pdf) And split into two Scrum teams, as described above.

Good luck with your transition! Feel free to come back and ask additional questions here on PMSE.

Comment: +1 for splitting up the team into feature teams. As you noted, 18 people is too many to be agile: it creates **153 communications channels** within the team. Ouch!